# Profiling garbage collection in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, garbage-collection, profiling

We're having problems with performance of the client-side JS code on our website, which are caused by semi-frequent Major GC operations. I would like to reduce the amount of these temporarily allocated and released objects, but I can't find a way to know what kind of objects are these, so:

**Is there a way to figure out what kind of objects are released during the Garbage Collection operation?** I couldn't find it in Chrome, but I would be happy to use any other browser... I would love to have allocation call stacks, but I would be happy with object types only too.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox and Chrome, you can right-click, select "Inspect", and then navigate to the "Memory" tab. Take a snapshot before and after the garbage collection occurs to see what's changing. Both browsers have a few different ways of looking at the way memory is allocated. Firefox, for example, has a nice tree view (in addition to other lists and breakdowns):
[image: Firefox Memory Tree View]

and since you mentioned Chrome, here's an example of a simple summary view where you can see individual objects and their size:
[image: Chrome Memory Summary View]